# What is the alternative in harmony OS for TableRow in android?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

What can be used in place of **TableRow** in harmony OS?
It is a part of **widget** package in android.

Answer (score 1):

Currently Harmony doesn't have any specific alternative for **[TableRow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow)**, but I would say there is no need for **TableRow** in **TableLayout** Component of Harmony OS, as you will be able to create **TableLayout** without **TableRow**, For Example

```java
    private TableLayout createTableLayout() {
        tableLayout = (TableLayout) mDialogLayout.findComponentById(ResourceTable.Id_md_table_layout);
        ComponentContainer.LayoutConfig layoutConfig = new ComponentContainer.LayoutConfig(ComponentContainer.LayoutConfig.MATCH_CONTENT,
                ComponentContainer.LayoutConfig.MATCH_CONTENT);
        tableLayout.setRowCount(getRowCount());
        tableLayout.setColumnCount(getColumnCount());
        tableLayout.verifyLayoutConfig(layoutConfig);
        for (int position = 0; position < getCount(); position++) {
            CircleView cv = new CircleView(mContext);
            cv.setLayoutConfig(cvlayoutConfig);
            tableLayout.addComponent(cv);
        }
        return tableLayout;
    }
```